# Adding data to 3 gridview on button click from 1 datatable

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have a DataTable which contains numbers from 1 - 12

on Button Click, i want to allocate this 12 numbers to my 3 gridviews,

GridView1 should contains 1 4 7 
GridView2 should contains 2 5 8 
GridView3 should contains 3 6 9

the numbers are to be allocated to the GridViews like that

Here is my code:

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn dc = new DataColumn();
    if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Grade", typeof(string));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        GridView A = new GridView { ID = "gv" + i.ToString() };
        Div1.Controls.Add(A);
    }

    ctr = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x <= count_table - 1; x++)
    {
        if (ctr == 3)
        { ctr = 0; }
        GridView B = Div1.FindControl("gv" + ctr.ToString()) as GridView;
        DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();
        NewRow[0] = stud_name[x];
        NewRow[1] = grade[x];
        dt.Rows.Add(NewRow);
        B.DataSource = dt;
        B.DataBind();
        ctr++;
    }
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method or  LINQ example could be below:

```
DataTable selectedTable = tb.AsEnumerable()
                            .Where(yourcondition)
                            .CopyToDataTable();
```

This would create a new `DataTable` based on filtered values.

If you use [`DataTable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx)

```
string expression = "Modul =" + value;
DataRow[] selectedRows = tb.Select(expression);
```

And then use the new data table to bind your gridview.